# How to update a column in sqlserver

Tags: sql-server, ruby, sql-update, tiny-tds

I'm trying to update a column in an SQL Server d/b in my ruby code using TinyTds - without success. When I take a copy of the query and run it manually using SQL Server Management Studio the update works fine, so I guess the syntax must be OK. I have no problem connecting to the d/b to run queries. Are there any particular options I need to set when creating the connection to enable updates?

Comment: Is login same in both cases?

Comment: Are there any error messages / stack traces?

Comment: Yes; the login is the same in both cases. There's no error message or stack trace as far as I can see. I did try to capture the return_code, but just got nil

Comment: have you captured the query using the profiler to see what exactly the application is sending to sql server ?

Comment: Yes; I captured and ran the same query manually in SQL Server Management Studio (using the same login credentials) and the update worked fine. Or am I misunderstanding the question here? What do you mean by 'the profiler'?

Comment: what are you doing to update using the tiny_tds code?

Comment: I'm creating a client connection to the database nad then executing an SQL query. This is the same approach I use to successfully run SELECT queries against the same table in the same database. However, when I run an UPDATE the data remains unchanged on the table. I've run this in debug mode and copied the query which is submitted; when run manually this has the desired effect of updating the data in the table. I'm getting a nil return code from TinyTDS but no error or exception that I know of.